# La comparution et la vidéo : formulations ?

Tags: vocabulaire, droit-et-justice, technologie

Peut-on dire d'une personne accusée d'une infraction pénale qu'elle :

> ...comparaît par [visiocomparution](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8359147/visiocomparution).
> ...comparaît par [visio/vidéoconférence](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8871726/visioconference).
> ...visiocomparaît.

Ces formulations sont-elles toutes acceptables et pourquoi en préférerait-on une, ou une différente ?

Answer (score 1):

En premier lieu, il ne me semble pas que le terme *visiocomparution* soit utilisé en français métropolitain. Une rapide recherche internet trouve principalement des sites québécois. Cela étant, c’est un néologisme relativement facile à comprendre ; je n'irai donc pas jusqu’à affirmer que c’est un emploi fautif. La troisième option qui l’utilise sous forme de verbe *(visiocomparaître)* me semble plus étrange, mais je n’ai pas d’argument rationnel pour faire la distinction avec l'usage du substantif.

Indépendamment de cela, j’éviterais la première formule *(comparaît par visiocomparution)* à cause de la répétition d'une même racine. Changer le verbe réglerait le problème *(est présent / est jugé / assiste au procès / ... par visiocomparution)*.

La deuxième proposition me semble la plus correcte et courante (toujours en français métropolitain), et peut être trouvée dans plusieurs articles du site dalloz-actualité ([exemple](https://www.dalloz-actualite.fr/flash/autorisation-du-recours-visioconference-pour-comparution-du-prevenu-detenu-devant-cour-d-appel)).